# 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-module, django-errors

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://54.235.168.5/mds/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['sana.mrs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'sana.mrs.util.LoggingMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/sana/urls.py" in <module>
  131.     (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'root'
```

The possible duplicate is [How to correct this error: "'Adminsite' object has no attribute 'root'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503616/how-to-correct-this-error-adminsite-object-has-no-attribute-root) .

where it is mentioned 
Your url for admin should be:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

not `(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)` 
- it's for Django 1.0. For Django 1.3 it wouldn't work.

then I got this error

NameError at /
name 'include' is not defined

```
    Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://54.235.168.5/mds/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['sana.mrs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'sana.mrs.util.LoggingMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/sana/urls.py" in <module>
  132.  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))

Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'include' is not defined
```

I am using Django Version 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you forgot the `from django.conf.urls.defaults import *` or `from django.conf.urls.defaults import include` in your urls.py.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
```

in your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't imported it:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import include
```

In general, when it says that something `is not defined`, it means that the compiler can't resolve something. This is usually caused by missing import statements or spelling errors.